# Powershell - separate elements in a ForEach loop with CSV data

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, foreach

I'm currently trying to create a phonebook xml generator that we can use to easily send to FTP server and access.

At the moment I have the following Powershell script;

```
----------
$csvPath = "C:\Users\nwong\Desktop\IDN_EXT.csv" 

[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xmlDocument = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

$directory = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("Directory")

$title_tag = read-host "Enter a title for your phonebook.."

$title = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("Title")

$menu_item = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("MenuItem")

$prompt = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("Prompt")

$ext = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("URI")

$xmlDocument.AppendChild($directory)

$directory.AppendChild($title)

$title.AppendChild($xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($title_tag))

ForEach ($e in (Import-CSV -Path $csvPath)) {  
    $directory.AppendChild($menu_item)
    $menu_item.AppendChild($prompt)
    $prompt.AppendChild($xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($e.Name))
    $menu_item.AppendChild($ext)
    $ext.AppendChild($xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($e.Extension))
 }


$xmlDocument.Save("C:\Users\nwong\Desktop\test.xml")

----------
```

At the moment, the script generates the following XML file

```
----------
<Directory>
   <Title>Test</Title>
   <MenuItem>
      <Prompt>OperatorKate ShanahanAtiq RAthman AIrfani DFelicity 
      PDeswanto</Prompt>
      <URI>50005001500250035004500550069</URI>
   </MenuItem>
</Directory>
---------
```

The result I'm looking for is something like this so it creates the element tags with each value found in the ForEach loop;

```
---------

<MenuItem>
     <Prompt>Operator</Prompt>
    <URI>625000</URI>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem>
    <Prompt>Kate Shanahan</Prompt>
    <URI>625001</URI>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem>
    <Prompt>Atiq R.</Prompt>
    <URI>625002</URI>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem>
    <Prompt>Athman A.</Prompt>
    <URI>625003</URI>
</MenuItem>`

----------
```

Should I have another loop that generates the same ForEach loop and split each individual value or is there an easier way to create separate element tags for each value in the CSV file?

Comment: Please edit the question and add sample input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo must create node into your loop, try this :

```
$csvPath = "C:\Users\nwong\Desktop\IDN_EXT.csv" 
$xmlPath = "C:\Users\nwong\Desktop\test.xml"

$title_tag = read-host "Enter a title for your phonebook.."

[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xmlDocument = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

$directory = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("Directory")
$xmlDocument.AppendChild($directory)

$title = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("Title")
$title.AppendChild($xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($title_tag))
$directory.AppendChild($title)

Import-CSV -Path $csvPath | %{

    $menu_item = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("MenuItem")

    $prompt = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("Prompt")
    $prompt.AppendChild($xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($_.Name))
    $menu_item.AppendChild($prompt)

    $ext = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("URI")
    $ext.AppendChild($xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($_.Extension))
    $menu_item.AppendChild($ext)

    $directory.AppendChild($menu_item)
 }

$xmlDocument.Save($xmlPath)
```